# How to join and union all two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `SCPOMGR.DFUTOSKUFCSTWIDE_VW_CHAIN` for **Forecast**  and `SCPOMGR.HistByChainAndEvent_VW` for **Sales**

I need to have 5 columns

1. Date (should be taken from both tables)
2. Chain (should be taken from both tables)
3. Item (should be taken from both tables)
4. Forecast (should be taken only from `SCPOMGR.DFUTOSKUFCSTWIDE_VW_CHAIN`)
5. Sales (should be taken only from `SCPOMGR.HistByChainAndEvent_VW`)

What I did so far: I both JOINED on chain only two tables (not sure if I need to join on anything else) and union all two tables. Here is my code:

```
SELECT Date, Chain, Item, Sales, Forecast

FROM 

(
SELECT s.DMDPostDate AS 'Date', s.LOC AS 'Chain', s.DMDUNIT AS 'Item', s.HistoryQuantity AS 'Sales', 0 AS 'Forecast'
  FROM SCPOMGR.HistByChainAndEvent_VW s
  JOIN SCPOMGR.DFUTOSKUFCSTWIDE_VW_CHAIN f
  ON   s.LOC=f.U_CHAINNAME
       WHERE s.DMDPostDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03' AND s.HistoryQuantity > 0
       
UNION ALL

SELECT f.STARTDATE AS 'Date', f.U_CHAINNAME AS 'Chain', f.DMDUNIT AS 'Item', 0 AS 'Sales', f.FORECAST_QTY AS 'Forecast'
  FROM SCPOMGR.DFUTOSKUFCSTWIDE_VW_CHAIN f
  JOIN SCPOMGR.HistByChainAndEvent_VW s
  ON   f.U_CHAINNAME=s.LOC
  WHERE f.STARTDATE BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03' AND f.FORECAST_QTY > 0
  

)
X

GROUP BY Date, Chain, Item, Sales, Forecast
```

The issue is that what I have is not a properly joined or unioned table. I have half of a table with `Date`, `Chain`, `Item`, `Sales` and all 0s for `Forecast` and later half of a table with `Date`, `Chain`, `Item`, all 0s for `Sales` and `Forecast`.

What I need is to have no repetition of the same rows, but everything filled for all datapoints: `Date`, `Chain`, `Item`, `Sales` and `Forecast`.

Picture of the issue that I have:

[image: Picture of the issue that I have]

Does anyone know how to join and union two tables at the same time? I appreciate your help.

After I edited the code with Gordon advice, I am getting this issue

[image]

The issue that I have after I added COALESCE.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAS7v.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: FYI Management Studio is not the database, its the client interface to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(s.DMDPostDate, f.STARTDATE) AS Date,
       COALESCE(s.LOC, f.U_CHAINNAME) AS Chain, 
       COALESCE(s.DMDUNIT, f.DMDUNIT) AS Item, 
       s.HistoryQuantity AS Sales, f.FORECAST_QTY as forecast
FROM (SELECT s.*
      FROM SCPOMGR.HistByChainAndEvent_VW s
      WHERE s.DMDPostDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03' AND
            s.HistoryQuantity > 0 
     ) s FULL JOIN
     (SELECT f.*
      FROM SCPOMGR.DFUTOSKUFCSTWIDE_VW_CHAIN f
      WHERE f.STARTDATE BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03' AND
            f.FORECAST_QTY > 0  
     ) f
     ON s.LOC = f.U_CHAINNAME AND
        s.DMDUNIT = f.DMDUNIT AND
        s.DMDPostDate = f.STARTDATE;
```

Comment: I have a diffrent issue right now.  Whenever I have forecast info but no sales info for that item it gives me null everywhere. I will attach the screenshot of an issue to my original post.

Comment: @JeremyU . . . That is fixed by using `COALESCE()`.  You probably also want to include the date in the `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: thank you. For some reason, I get some errors. If you may know how to fix them, I will greatly appreciate. I have attached the screenshot.